# JavaScript changing IDs won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to use the function `changeTab(num)` to change the ID of a li element from `number` to `selected`, and to revert selected tab's ID to its default number. It only works one or two times and then stops. My goal is to mimic the change of selected and unselected tab, like for example in Chrome tabs.

```
<ul id="nav">
                    <li onClick="changeTab(1);" id="1"><a  href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                    <li onClick="changeTab(2);" id="2"><a  href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                    <li onClick="changeTab(3);" id="selected"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
                    <li onClick="changeTab(4);" id="4"><a  href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
function changeTab(num){

    switch(num){
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("selected").id = "1";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("selected").id = "2";
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("selected").id = "3";
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("selected").id = "4";
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("selected").color = "";
    }


    //
    document.getElementById(num).id = "selected";
```

Comment: Don't do this with ids. Add and remove class names. Let the ids be constant.

Comment: That is a horrible abuse of the `switch` statement. Please use an `if...else` statement

Comment: Also note, that numeric IDs won't validate - ID attribute can't start with number.

Comment: @Zirak: if else would be equally unscalable, don't you think?

Comment: In addition to @WTK's comment: IDs and names share namespace so are historically interchangeable. Therefore IDs can automatically become JavaScript identifiers under certain situations e.g: document.myForm where `<form name="myForm">` (or in all situations if using Internet Explorer).  In JavaScript, identifiers are not allowed to start with a digit, this to prevent confusion with numeric literals.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski `if (num < 5) { ... } else { ... }` ?

Comment: @Zirak: No.  I meant having `if(x = 1) y = 1 else if(x = 2) y = 2...` can just be reduced to `y=x` given the context of the question.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Sure, literally translating it will also be an abuse of the `if...else` statement. But in the context of the question, there is a condition.

Comment: @Zirak: I get you now!  My fault for dismissing the `.color=""` because that seems to be dysfunctional (because there is no `color` DOM property and looking at the HTML/scenario, the user cannot change tab to an unknown tab).  It just looked like dead code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** as WTK suggested (as a comment in your question above) for this to be valid HTML, id values must start with a letter and not a number... I've updated my answer to be valid HTML by prepending the id with `nav-`...

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li onclick="changeTab(this);" id="nav-1"><a  href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
    <li onclick="changeTab(this);" id="nav-2"><a  href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
    <li onclick="changeTab(this);" id="selected"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
    <li onclick="changeTab(this);" id="nav-4"><a  href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using the `this` variable within the onclick handler will get the element being clicked... Then you can use the following function as the handler...

```
function changeTab(el) {
  // This function is passed 'el' from the onclick handler of the li. The
  // onclick handler passes 'this' through as the 'el' argument. 'el' will 
  // be a HTMLElement object. 

  // We only want to do something if the 'el' HTMLElement object does not
  // currently have the 'id' "selected", otherwise we do nothing.
  if(el.id != "selected") {
    // Revert all tabs to their original ids

    // Try and find the HTMLElement with the id "nav". The variable 'nav'
    // will be another HTMLElement object, this time representing the ul element.
    var nav = document.getElementById("nav");

    // The function 'getElementsByTagName' always returns a 
    // HTMLElementCollection, it might have zero elements if there were no
    // matches. We can use it as an array (although there are things to
    // take into consideration that affect performance). The 
    // HTMLElementCollection will contain all li elements that are 
    // descendants of the 'nav' ul element
    var lis = nav.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // Here we do a for-loop to iterate through the element collection
    // each item in the HTMLElementCollection will be a HTMLElement
    // representing one of the li elements
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; ++i) { // Arrays are zero-indexed

      // We set the id to nav-n overwriting whatever was there previously
      lis[i].id = "nav-" + (i + 1); // Our tabs are one-indexed
    }

    // Set the id for the original HTMLElement that was passed into the
    // function to "selected", we do this step last as one of the li HTMLElements
    // we change in the for-loop above will also be this HTMLElement
    el.id = "selected";
  }
}
```

There are other, possibly better, ways to do this. This should solve the problem though, if you wanted to delve deeper I would recommend the book Pro JavaScript Design Patterns.

Comment: +1: This works, and addresses the issue without lecturing. So solves the issue without adding well-intentioned confusion.

Comment: Thanks. The other comments would probably appear less lecturing if an attempt was made to provide a working answer to the question...

Comment: Who was that aimed at? What questions? If you can, make a new StackOverflow question if you can then you can get potentially a few thousand brains on the question rather than just three.

Comment: I have couple of questions, if you have time.
getElementsByTagName returns array because it returns all of li elements, is that correct? and variable el takes  value this, i don't understand how exactly is working(what type it is, and etc), so can you explain me this?

Comment: I've added comments to the answer to hopefully explain all of the steps

Comment: Did that help? Feel free to mark the question as answered as well ;-)

Comment: yes, this helped. I know understand the code you have written. X)